# TypeLoadException at startup of WCF

Tags: wcf

I get the following error long before I hit the breakpoint at Main().

> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException:
>   Unable to load one or more of the
>   requested types. Retrieve the
>   LoaderExceptions property for more
>   information.    at
>   System.Reflection.Module._GetTypesInternal(StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark)    at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.Tools.SvcHost.ServiceHostHelper.LoadServiceAssembly(String
>   svcAssemblyPath)

There is a suggestion that it might be a configuration error, but I don't see it when comparing to a similar, working example.

How do I "Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property" when it happens this early?

Thanks!

Comment: Any chance this happening on VS2010?

Comment: Sorry, Darin, I can't say; I don't have VS2010 yet.

Comment: Hi Kelly, I am having the exact same issue. Did you manage to solve the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Is there a chance that you have already installed the dll of this service in GAC and you modified the source code afterwards? If that's a case (like I experienced that myself) then just uninstall the dll and rebuild your service, that would make it work again.